# Installing Julia 0.4 in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, julia

The Ubuntu 15.10 release was announced a few days ago, so after upgrading I wanted to install Julia 0.4. However, I suspect there is not an installer ready for 15.10 since after adding the `staticfloat/juliareleases` PPA, I only was able to install Julia 0.3 (which is the same version offered by the Ubuntu Software Center)

Can anyone confirm this? Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**:

I asked the status of a PPA for Ubuntu 15.10 on Gitter. I was told that it might take a while before getting PPA for specific platforms. For now, the best option is to compile the source or to use the (precompiled) Generic Linux binaries.

Comment: Downvoter. Please explain why this is a bad question, so I can improve it.

Comment: If the PPA isn't working, you can also clone the `release-0.4` tag from [Github](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia), using `git clone https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia.git -b release-0.4` and then run `make` to build Julia yourself.

Comment: Sure, but the compilation takes forever on my computer and since 0.4 is already available, I wanted to take advantage of the PPA in Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Julia 0.4.1 was released for Ubuntu 15.10 on November 12. The PPA can be found [here](https://launchpad.net/~staticfloat/+archive/ubuntu/juliareleases).